# Query trougth yaml with terraform

Tags: for-loop, terraform, yaml

Hello i am trying to get a specific value out of my yaml file.

```
    gitlab_project_id: 1222
    name: testing-all
    hostnames:
      - name: testing-a
        external: true
        internal: true
        internal_stages: ["dev","qs"]
      - name: testing-b
        external: true
        internal: true
        internal_stages: ["dev","qs"]
```

I am using terraform `locals` to get the yaml data:

```
applications = [for filename in fileset(path.module, "apps/*.yml") : yamldecode(file(filename))]
```

In my query I am referring just to the first element inside hostnames, but if I delete the index after hostnames, the list is empty.

```
my_query = { for app_name, hostnames in { for app in local.applications : replace(lower(app.name), "/[\\s-]+/", "-") => app.hostnames if can(app.hostnames) } : app_name => hostnames.0 if try(hostnames.0.internal, false) }
```

My goal is to get a output something like this:

```
testing-all = {
           external        = true
           internal        = true
           internal_stages = [
               "dev",
               "qs",
            ]
           name            = "testing-a"
          },{
           external        = true
           internal        = true
           internal_stages = [
               "dev",
               "qs",
            ]
           name            = "testing-b"
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

While it is slightly unclear what you're after, it is clear you're probably over-complicating this a fair bit. First, I'm not sure if there are multiple yaml files, and you need to group them, or if there is one and you are just trying to matching it without giving the name explicitly. So, I've assumed there could be multiple and created a second. They are as follows.

#### apps/testing-all.yml

```yaml
    gitlab_project_id: 1222
    name: testing-all
    hostnames:
      - name: testing-a
        external: true
        internal: true
        internal_stages: ["dev","qs"]
      - name: testing-b
        external: true
        internal: true
        internal_stages: ["dev","qs"]
```

#### apps/testing-other.yml

```yaml
    gitlab_project_id: 5678
    name: testing-other
    hostnames:
      - name: testing-y
        external: true
        internal: true
        internal_stages: ["dev","qs"]
      - name: testing-z
        external: true
        internal: true
        internal_stages: ["dev","qs"]
```

The next issue is that your sample data, simply isn't valid data. You can't just connect objects with a comma, so I assume what you are after is a list of objects, one each per file / application, containing a list of objects housing the data within `hostnames` as shown.

This is done with:

#### main.tf

```
locals {
  applications = [
    for filename in fileset(path.module, "apps/*.yml")
    : yamldecode(file(filename))
  ]
}

output "application_map" {
  value = {
    for app in local.applications
    : app.name => app.hostnames
  }
}
```

Which yields:

```
Changes to Outputs:
  + application_map = {
      + testing-all   = [
          + {
              + external        = true
              + internal        = true
              + internal_stages = [
                  + "dev",
                  + "qs",
                ]
              + name            = "testing-a"
            },
          + {
              + external        = true
              + internal        = true
              + internal_stages = [
                  + "dev",
                  + "qs",
                ]
              + name            = "testing-b"
            },
        ]
      + testing-other = [
          + {
              + external        = true
              + internal        = true
              + internal_stages = [
                  + "dev",
                  + "qs",
                ]
              + name            = "testing-y"
            },
          + {
              + external        = true
              + internal        = true
              + internal_stages = [
                  + "dev",
                  + "qs",
                ]
              + name            = "testing-z"
            },
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Hello @theherk i restructured my question here. Thanks for your effort. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73637195/query-trough-yaml-and-create-custom-local-for-for-each-loop Hope you can understand my problem now.